# Comparison of XML Items

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am completely new to XML so I have no idea how to do this :

Suppose I have the following XML File 1 :

```
<Items>
<Item>
   <name> Item1 </name>
   <value> 10   </value>
</Item>
</Items>
```

and file 2 :

```
<Items>
    <Item>
       <name> Item1 </name>
       <value> 20   </value>
    </Item>
    </Items>
```

How do I compare value field of these 2 items in any way using XSLT ?

Comment: You can use the `document()` function to load secondary XML documents into variables, but what do you mean when you say you want to compare them? What do you want to do with that comparison?

Comment: [document()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256465.aspx) and [call-template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256487.aspx) with specifying 2 parameters will let you walk 2 XMLs at the same time... Note that it may be easier to use normal language to compare XML (unless you are good in functional languages - than XLST should be easy).

Comment: @JLRishe I want to store the change in another file . In this case , there would be the following entry in 3rd xml :

<changed>
    

    <Item>
       <name> Item1 </name>
       <value> 20   </value>
    </Item>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a stylesheet like the following to your first XML and pass in the path of the second XML document as a `param` (read the documentation of your XSLT processor on how to pass parameters).

The template will check each `<Item>` in XML #1, find the first item with the same `<name>` in the other XML (`$otherDoc//Item[name = $ownName][1]/value`) and compare their respective `<value>`s.

It would then generate text output, one line for each such comparison it makes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:param name="otherDocPath" select="''" />

  <xsl:variable name="otherDoc" select="document($otherDocPath)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- handle each item in this document -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Items/Item" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:variable name="ownName" select="name" />
    <xsl:variable name="ownValue" select="value" />
    <xsl:variable name="otherValue" select="$otherDoc//Item[name = $ownName][1]/value" />

    <!-- output one line of information per item -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($ownName, ': ')" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$ownValue = $otherValue">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('same value (', $ownValue, ')')" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('different (', $ownValue, '/', $otherValue, ')')" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text><!-- new line -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Beware of spaces around names/values. If your input really looks like `<value> 10   </value>`, you want to use `normalize-space()` before you compare/output anything (`<xsl:variable name="ownValue" select="normalize-space(value)" />` etc.).

Output would look like:

```
Item1: different (10/20)
Item2: same value (20)
Item3: different (20/)
```

where lines 1 and 2 stand for an item that are in both XML documents, line 3 stands for an item that is only in the first.

Of course text output is only one possibility, you could output different formats (XML, HTML).

Comment: What if i want the output to be like this :

    <Changed>
    <Item Name="Item1">
    <File1>10</File1>
    <File2>20 </File2>
    </Item>
</Changed>

Comment: @Aditya Then you change the XSLT to produce this output. (You are asking me to do your job for you. This is rude. I think my answer is more than enough to point you into the right direction. You will have to try for yourself.)